# Why binary rustc compiled with symbols stripped (strip=debuginfo or strip=symbol) does not run? Malformed Mach-o file

Tags: macos, rust, macos-ventura

I am trying to build a simple HelloWorld application with stripped symbols.
Compilation succeeds but when I try to execute it I get "Killed: 9" message (I am running MacOS).

compile command:

```
rustc main.rs -o main_stripped  -C strip=symbols
```

main.rs file:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

## Here is my environment information:

### Rust

```
$ rustup show
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/<user>/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown

active toolchain
----------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.65.0 (897e37553 2022-11-02)
```

### HW and OS

- Model: MacBook Pro
- Model Indentifier: MacBookPro18,2
- Chip: Apple M1 Max
- Total Number of Cores: 10 (8 performance and 2 efficiency)
- System Version: macOS Ventura 13.0.1 (22A400)

---

What I tried so far...

## dtrace/dtruss

received below output:

```
sudo dtruss ./main_stripped
dtrace: failed to execute ./main_stripped: Malformed Mach-o file
```

## compile without stripping

`rustc main.rs -o main`

I am able to run `main` binary

## inspect both binaries

```
$ file main_stripped
main_strip: Mach-O executable arm64
$ 
$ otool -h main_stripped
Mach header
      magic  cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
 0xfeedface 16777228          0  0x00           2    10       1440 0x00a00085
```

```
$ file main
main: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
$
$
$ otool -h main
main:
Mach header
      magic  cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
 0xfeedfacf 16777228          0  0x00           2    20       1960 0x00a00085
$
```

noticed a differences:

| binary | file | magic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| main_stripped | Mach-O executable arm64 | 0xfeedface |
| main | Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64 | 0xfeedfacf |

According to [mach-o/loader.h](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi2peqOvNP7AhV-hf0HHan_A1oQFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fopensource.apple.com%2Fsource%2Fxnu%2Fxnu-2050.18.24%2FEXTERNAL_HEADERS%2Fmach-o%2Floader.h&usg=AOvVaw3Sgaki5KdQ4zuf41a4KYMN) the magic 0xfeedface refers to **32-bit** architecture.

So for some reason architecture has changed to **32-bit** when using `strip=symbols`...

## strip symbols using another command

### tried `strip` command from GNU binutils 2.39 package

```
$ strip -v --strip-debug  -o main_stripped_2 main
copy from `main' [mach-o-arm64] to `main_stripped_2' [mach-o-arm64]
```

as a result I have received `main_stripped_2` which had also incorrect **32-bit** architecture..

```
$ file main_stripped_2
main_stripped_2: Mach-O executable arm64
$ 
$ otool -h main_stripped_2
main_stripped_2:
Mach header
      magic  cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
 0xfeedface 16777228          0  0x00           2    12       1544 0x00a00085
```

### tried `llvm-strip` command from LLVM version 15.0.5

```
$ llvm-strip -s -o main_stripped_3  main
```

as a result I have received `main_stripped_3` with correct **64-bit** architecture and was able to run. However, I am not sure what can I do with this information to fix my problem.

```
$ file main_stripped_3
main_stripped_3: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
```

## try another linker

Tried to used different linkers: `zld` or `mold`

```
rustc main.rs -o main_strip_mold  -C strip=debuginfo  -C link-arg=-fuse-ld=/opt/homebrew/bin/ld64.mold
```

again I have received binary in **32-bit** architecture

```
$ file main_strip_mold
main_strip_mold: Mach-O executable arm64
$
$ otool -h main_strip_mold
main_strip_mold:
Mach header
      magic  cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
 0xfeedface 16777228          0  0x00           2    15       2104 0x00a00085
```

## above steps work fine on another MacBook with below specs

- Model: MacBook Pro
- Model Indentifier: MacBookPro18,3
- Chip:   Apple M1 Pro
- Total Number of Cores:  8 (6 performance and 2 efficiency)
- System Version: macOS Monterey

What is different is chip and system version, but not sure if this is relevant to my problem.

---

Does anyone have a clue what could be the root cause of my problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
Root cause was as follows.

PATH was including path to homebrew binutils before system binaries, which led to resolving `strip` to `/opt/homebrew/opt/binutils/bin/strip` instead of `/usr/bin/strip`

For some reason binutils don't work as expected.